# Rails, Postgres, ActiveRecord query postgres based on columns value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, postgresql-9.3

I working with `Rails` and `Postgresql` and I'm trying to query my postgres db based on the value of a column.

To put it into perspective, I have an `Events` table in postgres and in that table I have some events that are recurring and some that aren't based on the column value of `repeats`.

If the events recur, then they will have a value of `daily`, `weekly`, `monthly`, etc. inside of the `repeats` column.  Obviously, if it doesn't recur then the value will be set to `null`.

I would like to receive only those events that recur in the `repeats` column. So if it's null, then the query will skip over it.

I've looked through the `ActiveRecord Query Interface` but due to my inexperience, I was unable to find a helper that would do the trick for me.

Please let me know if more info is needed.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Event.where.not(repeats: nil)
```

Alternatively, you can specify a sql stream

```
Event.where("repeats is not null")
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  Appreciate the help. @DVG